# Weird rendering in blender

Tags: rendering, texturing, 3d-view

When I import [this](http://www.scifi3d.com/details.asp?intGenreID=10&intCatID=8&key=534) 3d-model from the internet, it looks fine in 3ds Max but weird in Blender. Is there any quick way to fix this?

[image: This is how it looks in Blender.]

Comment: Could you add some context (what format? from where did you import?) - thx. Also, did you check your normals?

Comment: This was the first thing I thought too, but then I remembered an issue I've had before. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the OBJ file and imported it, and sure enough;

[image]

I've seen this issue before. I don't know if it's the default in blender, but my "Clip Start" value was incredibly small (0.01m). I changed it to 1m, and the model looks fine now;

[image]

Edit: It's also worth noting that this model is massive. I scaled it WAY down to work with it originally. However, I started with a fresh file, imported it, and the following settings work with the original scaling;

[image]

The "Clip start" was making the surface look weird. The "Clip end" was cutting off the back of the model.

Comment: thanks, that solved the issue.